# How can I get access/iterate through the elements of a pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Here is the series:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Series([], Name: ({"company": "Pennington PLC", "catch_phrase": "Future-proofed tertiary frame", "phone": "+1-312-296-2956x137", "timezone": "America/Indiana/Indianapolis", "client_count": 638}, nan, nan, nan), dtype: float64)
```

I want to get access to the value of Name, which is the dictionary.

[image]

Comment: Isn't it just `$df["Name"]`?

Comment: I get an error when I run that.

Comment: @Barmar I just added the data frame where I am getting the series from.  To access the third row of the dataframe, my code is df.iloc[2].  That yield the series Series([], Name: ({"company": "Pennington PLC", "catch_phrase": "Future-proofed tertiary frame", "phone": "+1-312-296-2956x137", "timezone": "America/Indiana/Indianapolis", "client_count": 638}, nan, nan, nan), dtype: float64)

Comment: Maybe `df["company"]`

Comment: @Barmar nothing.

Comment: It looks like you have an unhashable object as the name of a Series which shouldn't be possible. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: @dsaxton Actually, it looks like the name is a tuple containing a dictionary. That makes it hashable.

Comment: @Barmar Try running hash((1, dict()))

Comment: i think i got it.  df.name gives me the data.  its actually an empty series.  the Name: part is the name of the empty data.